# Searching a certain module for comparing arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, comparison, perl-module

Is there a module which can do this more nicely (not only replacing the smart-matching part)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my @array_all = ( qw( one two three four ) );
my @array_part = ( qw( two four six ) );

my @temp;
for my $i ( @array_part ) {
    push @temp, $i if not $i ~~ @array_all;
}

# if ( @temp ) { do something );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the *set difference* or perhaps the *relative complement*, the example is ambiguous. Any of the numerous [set modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=set) will suffice.

```
use Set::Object qw();
Set::Object
    ->new(qw(two four six))
    ->difference(Set::Object->new(qw(one two three four)))
    ->members;    # ('six')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.37/lib/List/Compare.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;
my @array_all  = ( qw( one two three four ) );
my @array_part = ( qw( two four six ) );
my @temp;
my $lc = List::Compare->new('--unsorted',\@array_all,\@array_part);
@temp  = $lc->get_complement;
print "@temp\n";
```